# Careers - Updating Profile Not Working

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs

It seems to be that I cannot update the responsibilities field if the text is more than 407 characters.

Testing with Chrome 25 and IE10 gets me the same results.

It seems that it will return properly if I have less than 408 characters.

The developer tools in Chrome (under the Network tab):
Request URL: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/updatesection/4100?sectionId=10411

With details on the form data looking correct, but the status is just (failed) with no response after 19 seconds (it always seems to timeout at that point).

On a normal entry, it returns a Status 200 (OK).

After some testing, it seems the failing point is at 408 characters.  The entire form data is 719 bytes.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this, can you give example text that fails to save which is more than 407 characters?